# curl php download script works fine in browser but fails in cronjobs

Tags: php, curl, download, cron, modx

I write curl php script which work is download csv file from one website after succesfully loged in. It works fine when i start it in my browser but it fails when i put it on cron jobs list. I seen memory exhausted error in my log once, so i guess my server give me less memory for cron.

How can i go around this problem?

You can see part of the code, which is doing download work, it's just usual :

```
<?php
...
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$fp = fopen("data.csv", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Just want to say again, this is part of the code and everything works fine in browser and fails in cron jobs.

Comment: What's the `crontab` entry (assuming it's a Linux OS)?

Comment: 0 */1 * * * cd /home7/philbike/public_html/atlanticauto/assets/components/cronmanager/ && php cron.php , but this is going to modx extension which execute snippet.

Comment: Just a thought - there are to different php.ini. It's a different for the execution from the command line (e.g. cronjobs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get everything works with my first settings: `cd /home7/philbike/public_html/atlanticauto/assets/components/cronmanager/ && php cron.php` .

I should write path to csv file as it is without using system variables:

```
/home7/philbike/public_html/atlanticauto/data.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this means that you're configuration of PHP (php.ini) is not the same when calling your server and when calling by command line. I'm not sure it's a best practice but I usually make my cronjob calling a wget on my scripts to be sure they are running in the same environment I tested them i.e. through a webserver.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *  *   *   *   wget -O - http://myapp.example.com/cron/run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The * indicate that the command will be run at any :

- minute
- hour
- day of the month
- month
- day of the week

The -O option tells wget to doesn't write the output of the script to a file
The "> /dev/null 2>&1" just redirect the ouput of the script to avoid the default behavior of cron (which is to send emails with command output to the users).

Comment: How it will looks in my case? I mean i execute 0 */1 * * * cd /home7/philbike/public_html/atlanticauto/assets/components/cronmanager/ && php cron.php , just add wget -O ?

Comment: No, of course not... wget waits an URL you just have to put the url you put in your browser to test. (I edit my answer to explain it).

Comment: Ok, i think i understand. But the point i can't use my script like that during security reason. I mean scripts starts in browser if i logged as admin in modx framework, but it cannot be executed but anyone else.

Comment: I usually add a key to my script (if the key is not in the get params I lock the execution) you can also check wether or not the request come from localhost or a local IP address like 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hi, i try your method. It gives me output                           HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `STDOUT'  0K                                                         298K=0s
2012-03-18 06:00:04 (298 KB/s) - `-' saved [4] 
Looks not very nice, i want save to data.csv file and this one save in STDOUT. %)

Comment: look at wget's man to save the ouput where you would like it to be saved

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using standard configuration of CRON, your `cwd` (current working directory) is `~/` or `/` or something like that, however when you're running script from the web your `cwd` is set to `dir( __FILE__)` (current script directory).

Say you're using script `/var/www/web1/scripts/script1.php`, than:

- webs cwd = `/var/www/web1/scripts/`
- CRONs cwd = `/var/www`

When you use relative file name such as `data.csv` (without `/` at the beginning) full path is created as `CWD . $filename`, therefore:

- webs full path `/var/www/web1/scripts/data.csv`
- CRONs full path `/var/www/data.csv`

You can easily avoid this by using:

```
define( 'PATH_ROOT', dirname( __FILE__) . '/');
// ...
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, PATH_ROOT . 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, PATH_ROOT . 'cookie.txt');
// ...
$fp = fopen( PATH_ROOT . "data.csv", "w");
```

Also make sure your system user is connect and script will run at all (check CRON long or send yourself an email).

Comment: If i will use "/" in beginning of my file like "/data.csv" should it works fine if file is inside public_html directory?

Comment: @electroid It will use file system root, you must either use `/var/www/public_html/data.csv` or (assuming that your script is in `/var/www/public_html/scripts/sub/cron.php`) `dir( __FILE__) . '/../../data.csv'`

Comment: anyway i allready try to execute it with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. i will try to do it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a workaround, you could execute this in browser without having to modify the PHP script. For example:

`30 * * * * /usr/bin/lynx -source http://mypage/status/cron > /dev/null`

It'll behave just like in browser, and will avoid you having to mess around with code and environment issues.

Alternatively, you could use wget instead of that PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

what about "php /home7/philbike/public_html/atlanticauto/assets/components/cronmanager/cron.php" command? Does it work in your terminal?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I can see log message in modx framework, which shows me what my snippets is executed.